# iOS 8: Best approach: Multiple UICollectionView in master detail format & singleton data source

Tags: ios, ios8, uicollectionview, datasource

I have two `UICollectionView`s C1 & C2 in a master detail layout on an iPad app. C1 is master collection view and displays primary data. When one taps on a cell in C1 then C2 will be updated and shows all objects information including the primary object information already being shown on C1.

Is it possible to have a single data source for both the collection views?
I thought out below given design for the data source

```
@protocol MyDataSourceDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
//Below method is called to notify collection view that a new object is added to the data source and so it must update its UI
- (void)didInsertItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

//Below method is called to notify collection view that an existing object is removed from the data source and so it must update its UI
- (void)didRemoveItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

@end

@interface MyDataSource : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSArray *fetchedObjects;//main objects array
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSArray *masterObjects;//array of objects displayed in master collectionview
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSArray *detailObjects;//array of objects displayed in detail collection view in multiple sections.

//called from within collection view when a cell is tapped
- (void)selectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath isMasterData:(BOOL)isMaster;

//call when a collectionview cell needs information for a particular cell's contents
- (id)itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath isMasterData:(BOOL)isMaster;
- (id)itemAtSection:(NSInteger)section isMasterData:(BOOL)isMaster;

@end
```

The problem with above implementation is that I want to keep data manipulation related work completely out of view controller hosting above two collection views so as to avoid bloating and same data source for both collection views. In above scenario how delegation will work between `collectionviews` and `MyDataSourceDelegate` protocol? As per my understanding delegation is a 1-1 relationships so how a single data source can be managed between two collection view?

Answer (score 0):

A data source is a very handy way to pass information around your application and can handle pretty much every class you choose to implement within your project. I use a data source mainly to handle a core data model, but I also use it for other things (passing around custom methods,etc).

I recently was using a data source for two tableview controllers, and this did cause some problems. However, if you keep your data separate in your data source for each collection view you should be okay. It WILL get harry when you start passing around properties (especially your arrays) between the controllers and the data source. You can run the risk of mutating your data.

A teacher of mine once said that the best programmers write the least amount of code. But if you find your data getting mutated, or you aren't getting the results back that you need, you may just need to implement it within your controller temporarily. Get it working and then decide the best way to move it to your data source. You might also consider creating similar properties for your arrays in each controller to store the information from your data source. You might be okay with immutable arrays, but if you're going to be manipulating the data you'll want to store it in a new property.

Consider the scenario below. I'm going to use the *fetchedObject array for my example.

#### DataSource.h

```
@interface DataSource : NSObject 

+(instancetype) sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *fetchedObjectsC1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *fetchedObjectsC2;

@property(nonatomic,strong)NSArray *masterObjects;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSArray *detailObjects;
```

Consider creating separate instances that are designated for each collection view.

#### DataSource.m

```
+(instancetype) sharedInstance{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    
    return sharedInstance;
}
- (void) fetchCoreData{
     //set up fetch
     self.fetchedObjectsC1 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]];
     self.fetchedObjectsC2 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]];

}
```

Now you have two separate instances populated with the same data. One for C1 and one for C2. This is how you would call them in a different class.

```
[DataSource sharedInstance].fetchedObjectsC1;
[DataSource sharedInstance].fetchedObjectsC2;
```

Consider a scenario where you're trying to populate two separate tableviews/collection views with the same instance of NSArray from your data source. When you start to implement canEditRowAtIndexPath: and other methods that manipulate your table view's data, you're also going to effect the functionality of the other collection view. Especially if you're saving/fetching from core data throughout this process. This will often result in a crash.

Based on the info that I have this is the best I could do, let me know if this doesn't work for you, and we'll work something else out. Don't forget to add your singleton to the data source and make sure its public.